# Any ideas how to create parameterised streaming api?

Tags: ruby, node.js, twisted, eventmachine, socket.io

I want to create parameterised streaming api like http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods#statuses-filter

The straightforward way I see is following:

1. Create redis channel for messages (like twitter statuses).
2. Each connected socket subscribes on this channel.
3. Inside redis callback each sockets check if current message fits supplied parameters (parameters could be set as separate socket message)

What you think guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [nats](https://github.com/derekcollison/nats)